# How do I enable descriptionSearch on the eBay API?

Tags: python, ebay-api

This is my code:

```
from ebaysdk.finding import Connection


page_number = 1
num = 1

try:
    api = Connection(appid='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', config_file=None, siteid='EBAY-DE')

    api_request = {
            'keywords': 'isbn',
            'categoryId': '267',
            'descriptionSearch': True,
            'paginationInput': {
            'entriesPerPage': '100',
            'pageNumber': page_number },
        }

    response = api.execute('findItemsAdvanced', api_request)


    reply = response.reply
    url = response.reply.itemSearchURL
    totalentries = response.reply.paginationOutput.totalEntries
    #item = response.reply.searchResult.item[num]

except :
  print "Error dude"

print url
print totalentries
```

My question is:

The descriptionSearch is not enabled although I set it to True.
What am I doing wrong?

The documentation states that descriptionSearch requires a boolean which I provided (see [here](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/finding/callref/finditemsadvanced.html#Request.descriptionSearch)).

The default setting for descriptionSearch False, but my code should have set it to True right?

Comment: can you try `'descriptionSearch': 'true',` ?

Comment: @karthikr, I tried that earlier and that actually works. Seems like a bug as  you would imagine that the api should take care of getting the dict into the correct json format.

Comment: I tried to see if the documentation would support what i said, but it looks like it is expecting a json dump rather than a  dictionary. @PadraicCunningham

Comment: @karthikr, the thing is calling json.dumps on the main dict then the api errors, what does work is setting it to `1`

Comment: 'descriptionSearch' : 'true', does not work either

Comment: setting it to 1 did work.

Comment: No.. It was @padriac